# Decomposition if matrix with strongly correlated columns

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose we have matrix $A\in M(p,p)$ and all columns of $A$ have unit $l_2$ norm. We also know that there is positive correlation between any pair of columns, i.e. $A_i'A_j >0$ (if it is helpful, we can assume that $A_i'A_j >K$ for some positive number $K$ - i.e. columns are strongly correlated).

Is it always possible to find orthogonal matrix $U$ such that matrix $UA$ has positive entries? In other words I would like to find algorithm to rotate strongly correlated columns to positive orthant without changing correlations between them (intuitively such rotation should be possible in described situation).

I have tried $QR$ and $SVD$ methods but them do not work. The most promising is polar decomposition $A=QP$, where $Q=UV'$ and $P=VDV'$ for $U,D,V$ coming from svd. This method worked in many cases (when correlations in simulations were strong ), i.e. the matrix $P =Q'A$ mostly had all entries positive.